# XMLHTTPREQUEST to Python Script Network error

Tags: javascript, python, xmlhttprequest

I've this python script in apache 2.2

```
#!/Python27/python


import sys, json

# Parse input into a json object
myjson = json.load(sys.stdin)

#get values
num1 = float(myjson['num1'])
num2 = float(myjson['num2'])
type = myjson['type']

#perform cal based on selection 
if type =="Add":
    total = num1 + num2
else:
    total = num1 - num2 



print'Content-Type: application/json\n\n'
print json.dumps( {'ans':total})
```

I tried to do a xmlhttprequest, but getting network error. why?

```javascript
//Address to post to 
var url = "http://localhost/demo/calculate.py";

//Create json object
var json = '{"num1":' + num1 + ', "num2":' + num2 + ',"type":"' + type + '"}';

var output = document.getElementById("updateMe");
output.innerHTML += "send";

try {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url, false)
    xhr.send(json);
} catch(e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

Comment: Please tell me why you create JSON using string functions? That's a HORRIBLE idea. Use this code instead: `var json = JSON.stringify({num1: num1, num2: num2, type: type});`

Comment: Also, why are you running your python script as CGI and not using mod_wsgi (or at least mod_python even though using mod_wsgi and a microframework is cleaner)